# How to code for SearchView on ActionBar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am not able to get the filter value from the list. 
For the wrong search the list shows blank page, when I enter the right value, only the first value from the list is fetched.
After implementing OnQueryTextListener to my class, I inserted the following code:-

Please help. Thanks in Advance

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
     SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}




@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
        lv.clearTextFilter();
    }else{
        lv.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

Implementing Filterable in Adapter class

```
public Filter getFilter(){
    return null;

}
```

I Added the above method, now there is NullPointerException generated.

Comment: having you implement filtrable in adapter?

Comment: No I have not implemented filterable in adapter. would be grateful if u guide me hw to implement it for my above code

Comment: Please tel me what needs to be added in the getFilter().

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial it uses Sherlock Action Bar, it shows exactly what you are trying to do. I have used it and works great. http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-search-collapsible-view-in-android/